# in Gwt, how to make the text of checkbox bold?

Tags: gwt, checkbox, fonts, font-face

in GWT, how to make the text of checkbox bold?, there is no setFont in CheckBox

```
CheckBox boldCheckBox=new CheckBox("ok");

boldCheckBox.setFont()???
```

Anyone know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
chk.getElement().getStyle().setFontSize(14, Unit.PT);
```

I recommending this for more [possibilities](http://blog.francoismaillet.com/?p=68)

Comment: Checkbox labels are actually inside a span element, so, if you have some overriding CSS, this won't work.  You need to explicitly set the value on the label, like this:  ((Element)chk.getElement().getChild(1)).getStyle().setFontSize(14, Unit.PT);

Answer (score 3):

Google seems to recommend using CSS whenever possible with GWT.

Use something like this when creating the checkbox:

```
CheckBox boldCheckBox = new CheckBox("ok");
boldCheckBox.addStyleName("cbstyle");
```

and then put this in your css file:

```
.cbstyle {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use CCS:
You have to use a CCS class and call the class in the checkbox, or you can use inline CCS as well.

```
font-weight: bold;
```

Or, You can use the way suggested by Baadshah.

Answer (score 0):

Despite you can do it via **CSS** as others mentioned, there is another easier way:

```
CheckBox boldCheckBox=new CheckBox("ok");
boldCheckBox.getElement().getStyle().setFontWeight(FontWeight.BOLD);
```

Comment: This answer is already explained in the link provided in the accepted answer. No idea why to bring up a 4year old thread for this.

Comment: To help someone else like myself who needs a little bit of help after 4 years of this discussion and maybe much more years after. And of course i believe my answer is more related to the question than other friends.